# not able to parse XML with jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, parsexml

```
    var xmlData = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<InfoPostRpt>
<Band>
<ColumnHeaders>
  <ColumnHeader id="1" prefix="k_">
    <RptFld align="left" val="TSP_Name"></RptFld>
    <RptFld align="left" val="TSP_Prop"></RptFld>
    <RptFld align="left" val="K_Holder_Name"></RptFld>
    <RptFld align="left" val="K_Holder_Prop"></RptFld>
    <RptFld align="left" val="Svc_Req_K"></RptFld>
    <RptFld align="left" val="K_Beg_Date"></RptFld>
    <RptFld align="left" val="K_End_Date"></RptFld>
    <RptFld align="left" val="K_Ent_Beg_Date"></RptFld>
    <RptFld align="left" val="K_Ent_End_Date"></RptFld>
    <RptFld align="left" val="K_Ent_Beg_Time"></RptFld>
    <RptFld align="left" val="K_Ent_End_Time"></RptFld>
    <RptFld align="left" val="Cap_Type"></RptFld>
    <RptFld align="left" val="Cap_Type_Name"></RptFld>
    <RptFld align="left" val="K_Stat"></RptFld>
  </ColumnHeader>
</ColumnHeaders>    

</Band>
</InfoPostRpt>";

alert ( xmlData );
```

I tried to parse XML using jQuery.parseXML( xmlData ) but it gives parsing error without any deatils.

What's missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var xmlData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
"<InfoPostRpt>" +
"<Band>" +
"<ColumnHeaders>" +
"  <ColumnHeader id=\"1\" prefix=\"k_\">" +
"    <RptFld align=\"left\" val=\"TSP_Name\"></RptFld>" +
"    <RptFld align=\"left\" val=\"TSP_Prop\"></RptFld>" +
"    <RptFld align=\"left\" val=\"K_Holder_Name\"></RptFld>" +
"    <RptFld align=\"left\" val=\"K_Holder_Prop\"></RptFld>" +
"    <RptFld align=\"left\" val=\"Svc_Req_K\"></RptFld>" +
"    <RptFld align=\"left\" val=\"K_Beg_Date\"></RptFld>" +
"    <RptFld align=\"left\" val=\"K_End_Date\"></RptFld>" +
"    <RptFld align=\"left\" val=\"K_Ent_Beg_Date\"></RptFld>" +
"    <RptFld align=\"left\" val=\"K_Ent_End_Date\"></RptFld>" +
"    <RptFld align=\"left\" val=\"K_Ent_Beg_Time\"></RptFld>" +
"    <RptFld align=\"left\" val=\"K_Ent_End_Time\"></RptFld>" +
"    <RptFld align=\"left\" val=\"Cap_Type\"></RptFld>" +
"    <RptFld align=\"left\" val=\"Cap_Type_Name\"></RptFld>" +
"    <RptFld align=\"left\" val=\"K_Stat\"></RptFld>" +
"  </ColumnHeader>" +
"</ColumnHeaders></Band></InfoPostRpt>";
jQuery.parseXML(xmlData);
```

The above works just fine for me. The string needs to be on a single line (or you can use string concatenation like I did), and you need to escape the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I used this online tool to convert XML to JAVA compatible literal : http://xmltoolbox.appspot.com/